# Symfony5 - update user profile cause logout when edit form submitted

Tags: php, symfony5

I try to set an « edit your profile » functionality. My users are loaded using an entity provider.

A user is identified by email and password.
When I try to update my user using the form I am always logged out even when a form error occurs.

UserEntity

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Department;
use App\Entity\Level;
use App\Entity\Region;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $user_lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $user_firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $user_birthdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Region")
     */
    private $user_region;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Department")
     */
    private $user_department;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $user_description;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Level")
     */
    private $user_level;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $user_profil_picture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $user_confirmation_token;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(?string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(?array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(?string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function setUserLastName(?string $user_lastname): self
    {
        $this->user_lastname = $user_lastname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserLastname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_lastname;
    }

    public function getUserFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_firstname;
    }

    public function setUserFirstname(?string $user_firstname): self
    {
        $this->user_firstname = $user_firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->user_birthdate;
    }

    public function setUserBirthdate(?\DateTimeInterface $user_birthdate): self
    {
        $this->user_birthdate = $user_birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserDepartment(): ?Department
    {
        return $this->user_department;
    }

    public function setUserDepartment(?Department $department): self
    {
        $this->user_department = $department;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserRegion(): ?Region
    {
        return $this->user_region;
    }

    public function setUserRegion(?Region $region): self
    {
        $this->user_region = $region;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_description;
    }

    public function setUserDescription(?string $user_description): self
    {
        $this->user_description = $user_description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserLevel(): ?Level
    {
        return $this->user_level;
    }

    public function setUserLevel(?Level $level): self
    {
        $this->user_level = $level;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserProfilPicture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_profil_picture;
    }

    public function setUserProfilPicture(?string $user_profil_picture): self
    {
        $this->user_profil_picture = $user_profil_picture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserConfirmationToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_confirmation_token;
    }

    public function setUserConfirmationToken(?string $user_confirmation_token): self
    {
        $this->user_confirmation_token = $user_confirmation_token;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

UserType

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Department;
use App\Entity\Level;
use App\Entity\Region;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\RepeatedType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * EntityManagerInterface
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    private $security;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, Security $security)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Build the register form
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user_lastname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Doe',
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^[\wéèêàäâçïöôîûüù\' \-]+$/',
                        'message' => 'La chaîne comporte des caractères non autorisés',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Prénom',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'John',
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 3 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^[\wéèêàäâçïöôîûüù\' \-]+$/',
                        'message' => 'La chaîne comporte des caractères non autorisés',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_birthdate', DateType::class, [
                'label' => 'Date de naissance',
                'html5' => false,
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année',
                    'month' => 'Mois',
                    'day' => 'Jours',
                ],
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'jj/mm/aaaa',
                ],
                "format" => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'by_reference' => true,
                'invalid_message' => 'Format de date incorrect',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Adresse email',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'john.doe@exemple.com',
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Email(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_region', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Région',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez une région',
                'class' => Region::class,
                'choice_label' => 'region_name',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_department', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Département',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un département',
                'class' => Department::class,
                'choice_label' => 'department_nom',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_level', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => 'Niveau',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez votre niveau',
                'class' => Level::class,
                'choice_label' => 'level_name',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_description', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 3 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => ['label' => 'Mot de passe'],
                'second_options' => ['label' => 'Confirmation mot de passe'],
                'invalid_message' => 'Les champs mot de passe doivent être identiques',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 3 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_profil_picture', FileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Image profil',
                'data_class' => null,
                'constraints' => [
                    new File([
                        'maxSize' => '1024k',
                        'mimeTypes' => [
                            'image/png',
                            'image/jpeg',
                            'image/gif',
                        ],
                        'mimeTypesMessage' => 'Please upload a valid PDF document',
                    ]),
                ],

            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => User::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Profile Controller

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Department;
use App\Entity\Level;
use App\Entity\Region;
use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\Type\UserType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class ProfilController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/profil", name="profil")
     */
    public function homeAction()
    {
        // Recupere l'utilisateur courant
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (null === $user) {
          return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }
        
        return $this->render('profile/profile.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/profil/editer", name="edit_profil")
     */
    public function editerProfilAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        // Recupere l'utilisateur courant
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (null === $user) {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        // Creation du formulaire d'edition
        $editUserForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

        // On indique au formulaire de prendre en charge le contenu de la requete
        // Il va mapper les different champs soumis avec le contenu de l entite $user
        $editUserForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            if ($editUserForm->isSubmitted() && $editUserForm->isValid()) {
                
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                // Region
                $region = $em->getRepository(Region::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $editUserForm['user_region']->getData()]);
                $user->setUserRegion($region);

                // Department
                $department = $em->getRepository(Department::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $editUserForm['user_department']->getData()]);
                $user->setUserDepartment($department);

                // Level
                $level = $em->getRepository(Level::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $editUserForm['user_level']->getData()]);
                $user->setUserLevel($level);

                // Encodage du mot de passe
                $user->setPassword($passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                    $user,
                    $user->getPassword()
                ));
                // definition du role ROLE_USER
                $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

                $token = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode(random_bytes(32)), '+/', '-_'), '=');
                $user->setUserConfirmationToken($token);
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                // TO DO ENVOYER UN MAIL DE CONFIRMATION POUR ACTIVER LE COMPTE

                $this->addFlash(
                    'success',
                    'Vos modification ont bien etes enregistrees.'
                );

                return $this->redirectToRoute('profil');
            }
        }

        // Affichage
        return $this->render('profile/edit_profile.html.twig', [
            'form' => $editUserForm->createView(),
            'libAction' => 'Modifier'
        ]);
    }
}
```

How can allow user to edit its informations including his email (which is actually the unique identifyer) without be logged out ?

**EDIT1**

Found that the problem is the password field. As the password is required in UserType on submitting Symfony changes password using the `setPassword` method, then execute the validation.

The form is not valid so not submitted but as the password is now `null` Symfony kicks me out.

There is a way to make password optional on edit? Should I create another form builder especially for edit?

**EDIT2**

I found an interresting way to handle this issue using the DTO (data transfert object) trick. I created a EditUserDTO class which has exaclty same constraints as my User entity except for password which is no more mandatory. That object is uses by my UserType like

```php
$user = $this->getUser();
$dtoUser = EditUserDTO::createFromEntity($user);
$editUserForm = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $dtoUser, ['data_class' => EditUserDTO::class]);
```

This way I'm able to not trigger logout because my User Entity has not changed

Comment: You should also implement `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface`, this would allow you to define that a changed password does not mean the user changed. Ref: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#comparing-users-manually-with-equatableinterface

Comment: I read some issues on Github about EquatableInterface but I didn't find any example how to use it maybe you can provide me sample with the `isEqualTo` method ?

Comment: Check `\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`. It has a fully implemented example.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how it could help me right now

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is that when the user changes their email, the security component assumes it's a new user, and logs them out. (See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session) So you have two options (re-login, which is *kinda* annoying on it's own) or tell symfony, that the user didn't change. The simplest way would be to implement an `isEqualTo` method that only compares another, immutable quality of the user entity (e.g. the primary key?).

Comment: Actually changing email works and according to the documentation it shouldn't since AbstractToken class compares the return value of the getUsername() method which in my case returns email

Comment: If I don’t map the password field to my user object I’m not logged out